# make condition on environment.prod.ts file

Tags: php, node.js, angular, angular-ui-router, node-modules

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UY8o.png)

How could I make the condition in below code and `environment.ts` file.

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  if(our condiion = "impdev.something.com"){
   API_url:'https://impdev.something.com/Angular',
  }
  if(our condiion = "dev.something.com"){
    API_url:'https://dev.something.com/Angular',
  }
  if(our condiion = "app.something.com"){
    API_url:'https://app.something.com/Angular',
  }

};
```

Comment: you can not add condition in environment.ts file but in service you can create the function which will decide the enviromnet

Comment: ok, @TheParam but what is the best way to do this. because i have 3 envirnment

Comment: I have added the best way to achieve solution to this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will achieve this in other way using following solution.

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  dev: { serviceUrl: 'https://dev.something.com' },
  stage: { serviceUrl: 'https://stage.something.com' },
  prod: { serviceUrl: 'https://prod.something.com' },
  local: { serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/' },
};
```

**NetworkService.ts**

```
export class NetowrkService {

  url: string;
  env: string
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.env = this.setENV();
    this.url = environment[this.env].serviceUrl;
  }

  setENV() {
    if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("dev") != -1) {
      return "dev";
    } else if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("stage") != -1) {
      return "stage";
    } else if (window.location.hostname.indexOf("localhost") != -1) {
      return "local";
    } else {
      return "prod";
    }
  }


   // Call rest API
}
```

Comment: yes its working but , is there any possible use this in common because in this project we add approx 10 -12 service file.

Comment: create a parent service class and inherit this in your all 12 services. that's what we are doing. there is no way to add condition in object

Answer (score 1):

idk if it's what you want, but in `angular.json` ctrl + f to search for `fileReplacements`, in here you can tell Angular which environment folder file to replace with which under the different modes.. then you can access the same variable in `environment.ts` though your whole app, and it will be replaced automatically depending on your serve or build setups.

if unsure, just copy-paste the whole "production" JSON tha tcointains the `fileReplacements` property, and change the `replace` value with a new environment.ts file that you created (as in `environment.dev.ts`) and then copy all the variables from one environment to another and change values, and use them through the app

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator here,

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  API_url: your_condition_here ? '' : '';
};
```

But from where you will get the condition here?

Comment: This is my question how to get conditional here

Comment: When you will check these conditions? means explain a bit your flow

Comment: Means that possibility of condition on this page

Answer (score 0):

Main.ts

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  animal: ''
};
```

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  animal: ''
};
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent {
  animal: string = environment.animal;
}
```